# Salesforce Report Visibility Customization

Tags: filters, custom-reports, criteria-based-sharing, organization-wide

I want to implement a feature for customizing report visibility based on a User(Logged in user) field value.

For e.g -

A is report of record B ;
C & D are particular field values of B & User respectively -

I want to customize report filters as when C & D values are same.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I was successful in resolving this issue using a custom formula field value. I made it result 1 if C=D and 0 if not...based on this value I created the report filter, thanks for all the suggestions by the way..

Anyone facing the same issue can get in touch :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked "Filter Reports via URL Parameters"? https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.reports_filter_url.htm&type=5

For example, you can add a button link on an Account layout that will open a report with a filter by current account ID:

*/lightning/r/Report/00OE00000019cv9/view?fv0={!Account.Id}*

where

- 00OE00000019cv9 - is a unique report record id.
- fv0= first filter in the report
- {!Account.Id} - a dynamic value from an account record.

Then you can add more filters to the report and params in the url.

If it's not exactly what you need, please share additional details.

Answer (score 0):

**Sorry, Currently Salesforce doesn't have any functionality to enable report visibility based on any Custom Object or User field values.**

You can only able to enable report visibility based on Folder Permissions as per [this](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.analytics_folder_access.htm&type=5) link.

Which will require user level access[Basic] as per [this](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.analytics_sharing_permissions.htm&type=5) link.